# Linker Error when using Google Play Services and Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, linker, google-play-services, google-play-games

I currently want to use Leaderboards from Google Play Services in Unity 5.
When I run the project on the device I receive a huge amount of linker errors:

[image]

I followed the instructions on https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity#ios-setup. After the export I added the listed bundles and libraries. To be precise I have (dowloaded from https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/):

- Play Games C++ SDK Version 1.4 (GoogleOpenSource.framework, GooglePlus.bundle, GooglePlus.framework)
- Google-plus-ios-sdk-1.7.1 (gpg.framework, gpg.bundle)

I also made sure I set the -ObjC compiler flag. And I am sure I added the list of iOS libraries that are required by Google Play Services (AddressBook.framework, AssetsLibrary.framework, CoreData.framework, CoreTelephony.framework, CoreText.framework, Security.framework, libc++.dylib, libz.dylib). iOS Target is set to 7.0 and higher. You can see the library setup and bundle resources here (I cut of the non G+ libraries for a smaller graphic):
[image]

The errors seem to indicate a missing library. However I checked that the libraries are in the projects folder and linked in the binary libraries under Build Phases.

The only discrepancy between my setup and the documentation I could find is that there is no GooglePlayGames.bundle, but it now seems to be named gpg.bundle instead. However this should not result in linker errors.

**Do you have any idea what could cause these errors?**

Comment: The zip file containing the library has been updated and the symbols are there now.  Can you download a new copy of the 1.4 SDK and try again?

Comment: The new files work! Thank you. I thought that this might be the problem. That is when I tried to find the 1.3 version of the SDK. Is there any way to access older versions of those libraries?